# sum of infinite terms of a convergent serie

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, summation, newton-series

I am trying to calculate:

$\begin{equation} \sum_{j=0}^{\infty} (\frac{\lambda^j}{j!})(\frac{\lambda^{j+h}}{(j+h)!}) \end{equation}$

And then, I did:

$\begin{equation} \sum_{j=0}^{\infty}  (\frac{\lambda^{2j+h}}{(j+h)!(j)!}) = \sum_{j=0}^{\infty}  (\frac{\lambda^{2j+h}}{(j+h)!(j)!}) \times (\frac{(j+h+j)!}{(j+h+j)!}) = \sum_{j=0}^{\infty} \begin{pmatrix}
2j+h  \\
j
\end{pmatrix} \times \frac{\lambda^{2j+h}}{(2j+h)!} \end{equation}$

But how can I prove this result, in fact, converges and to which result?

Answer (score 1):

These are simply [modified Bessel functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function#Modified_Bessel_functions:_I%CE%B1,_K%CE%B1):

$$I_h(2\lambda)=\sum_{j=0}^\infty\frac{\lambda^j}{j!}\frac{\lambda^{j+h}}{(j+h)!}$$

Absolute convergence trivially follows by comparison to $e^x$'s Maclaurin expansion, the ratio test, etc.